# Row formatting based on a LOOKUP column value in modern SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Modern experience SharePoint List A has a LookUpColumn that retrieves values from NumberColumn in ListB. I need conditional formatting that applies a color across an entire row based on a value in the LookUpColumn.

Currently, lookup columns are not catered for OOTB. So far, I applied JSON but it formats only the column. How do I format an entire row when it is based on a LOOKUP column?

Update:
Screenshot show current impact of formatting for row and column:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [use view formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) to customize entire row in a SharePoint list.

[image]

If you want to just apply the colors to entire row, you should use `additionalRowClass` property to format the view.

**Example**: Considering internal name of your lookup column is `LookUpColumn`, you can use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 75, 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] < 75 && [$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 50, 'sp-field-severity--low', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] < 50 && [$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 25,'sp-field-severity--warning', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] < 25,'sp-field-severity--blocked', ''))))"
}
```

You can get the correct internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Similarly, you can apply any of the predefined classes given in below links as per your requirements:

1. [Predefined classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#predefined-classes)
2. [Reusable SharePoint Online Classes for Modern UI](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/)

---

**Update from comments**:

If `[$lkpMile.lookupValue]` is not working, try using `[$lkpMile]` instead of `[$lkpMile.lookupValue]`.

Not sure why `[$lkpMile.lookupValue]` is not working for you. I have tried it my end & it is working fine for me.

Lookup column settings:

[image]

List view formatting output with simple JSON:

[image]

---

Microsoft documentation also says,

> The lookup field object has the following properties (with example values):

```
{
   "lookupId": "100",
   "lookupValue": "North America",
}
```

**Source**: [JSON formatting - Special string values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#special-string-values) - check "Lookup fields" section

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code but I keep getting "Incorrect type. Expected "object". And yes, source values are numbers as per the example you used. How do I clear the error?

Comment: Did you use the correct internal name of your lookup column? Can you add a screenshot of list view or lookup column settings to your original question?

Comment: Yes I did. Progress but not there yet...the above error is no more, but now ALL values disappear from the column (at least I know the code is picking up the correct internal name, right?), including values that do not meet the condition.

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: Hi. No it's not...status is still " ALL values disappear from the column" and I can't figure out why that's happening.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of list view or lookup column settings and the current code you are using to your original question? That will help us to troubleshoot the exact issue & answer your question more precisely.

Comment: I have added screenshots to the original question, thank you

Comment: Why there are green squiggly lines in your code? What error message it shows when you hover over it? Also, can you try using `[$lkpMile]` instead of `[$lkpMile.lookupValue]`.

Comment: Yessss, thank you! I removed the lookupValue, tweaked it and it's working (why though?). A few issues: The "error" from the green squiggly lines ("Incorrect Type. Expected "object") is still there even though the code is working...any idea? Is it really an error or more informational/warning because of it being a lookup? Secondly, the value zero is a bit odd...the code didn't pick it up with <, >, >=, or <= but it works as == "0"...maybe a technical explanation could help the community. Lastly, I changed to ms-bgColor-orange, ms-bgColor-orangeLighter etc. Thank you very much!

Comment: Green squiggly lines are warnings of editor & not error. Not sure why `.lookupValue` is not working for you, maybe because of how you setup the lookup column. Check my updated answer to see how I have setup lookup column settings.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the updated answer. I shall double-check my lookup column settings and compare them with yours.

Comment: Sure, check your lookup column settings and let me know if any further help needed.

Comment: I apologize, that was my mistake, please confirm, this is the first time I'm actually using this platform's features

Comment: No problem. I was just checking. keep asking questions on this forum.

Comment: Please advise if this warrants a new question, but I believe it is an extension of this one: how do I use the same code to highlight a row if, say, columnABC is empty? I tried everything from =if([$LookUpColumn] == '', =if([$LookUpColumn] == "" etc but that's not working. How do I check for the absence of a value and highlight the entire row? Thank you

Comment: You can add one more `if` condition to check if column is blank. please create a new question & I will provide complete JSON and explanation in the separate answer.

Comment: [new question added](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299415/format-sharepoint-list-row-based-on-empty-column-using-json) thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.In my test, this is the [NumberColumn] field and the [LookUpColumn] field

[image]

2.Go to your ListA, click **All Items** >> **Format current view**

[image]

3.On the Format View windows, click "**Advanced mode**" link

[image]

4.Paste the below JSON formatting and click Save

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "style": {
    "font-style": "ms-fontColor-alert"
  },
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 7, 'ms-bgColor-white', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] <= 7 && [$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 3, 'ms-bgColor-yellow',  if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] <= 3,'ms-bgColor-orangeLighter', '')))"
}
```

[image]

[image]