# Format SharePoint List row based on empty column using json

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience, json-formatting

How do I extend the solution [provided here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299232/row-formatting-based-on-a-lookup-column-value-in-modern-sharepoint-list/299233?noredirect=1#comment316600_299233) to highlight a row if, say, column "LookUpColumnABC" is empty?

I tried incorporating if([$LookUpColumnABC] == '', if([$LookUpColumnABC] == "" and similar code into [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299232/row-formatting-based-on-a-lookup-column-value-in-modern-sharepoint-list/299233?noredirect=1#comment316600_299233) but that's not working.

How do I check for the absence of a value and highlight the entire row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing to an empty string as you are showing is fine in most cases. But you can also use the `length` operator which seems to cover all cases equally well. I'm not sure everything you're trying to accomplish, but here's a very basic view format using this logic to make rows with empty values in the `Lookup` column red and others blue:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(length([$Lookup])==0,'ms-bgColor-red','ms-bgColor-blue')"
}
```

`length` is used to determine the number of items in an array (not string length) and for anything other than arrays always returns 1 when a value is present and 0 when not.

Comment: Thank you, using the length function works, but I did have to append lookupValue to this particular column like so: if(length([$Lookup.lookupValue])==0

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue], if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 75, 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] < 75 && [$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 50, 'sp-field-severity--low', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] < 50 && [$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] > 25,'sp-field-severity--warning', if([$LookUpColumn.lookupValue] < 25,'sp-field-severity--blocked', '')))), '')"
}
```

**Example**:

[image]

Here I am using the simple expression like:

```
if([$LookUpColumnABC.lookupValue], "Value available", "Value not available")
```

I am referring the "Simplest way" provided in this article: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)